# unable to import Postgres Fixture from class

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have created a class to spin up a test db that i will use in sql test cases for testing custom airflow operators. I'm still trying to figure out the correct way to import the fixture from the class and still learning pytest. Class is as follows:

import json
import testing.postgresql
import psycopg2
import pytest
from pytest_postgresql import factories

```
class MockPostgres:
    def __init__(self, Postgresql):
        self.Postgresql = Postgresql

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def db_session(self):
        postgresql = factories.postgresql('postgresql_my_proc',
                                                         load=['postges-init.sql'])
        return postgresql
```

I then import this into my testcase as

```
from .....mocks.postgres import MockPostgres
```

I then create my testcase as

```
class TestOperator(TestCase):

    def test_postgres_operator(self, mocker):
        mocker.patch.object(
            PostgresHook,
            "get_connection",
            return_value=Connection(
                conn_id="postgres",
                conn_type="postgres",
                host="localhost",
                login="testuser",
                password="testpass",
                port= postgres.ports["5432/tcp"][0],
            ),
        )

        #target Postgres Container for
        task = TestOperator(
            task_id="TestOperator",
            postgres_conn_id="postgres_id",
        )

        pg_hook = PostgresHook()

        row_count = pg_hook.get_first("select * from test")[0]
        assert row_count >1
```

What am I missing? Getting an error

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```